# Exclude Top Line in Grep -A2

Tags: unix

I'm learning UNIX coding. I have a text file with various descriptions and specified paths.

I run the following:

```
fgrep ${PWD:16:100}/description ../../PA1/descriptions.txt -A2
```

This returns:

```
==> ./buttonRoom/description <==
Maze button room
You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike.
```

How do I exclude the line `==> ./buttonRoom/description <==`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this after initial grep:

```
| grep -v '==>'
```

Or just remove first line:

```
| sed '1d'
```